# `Shift` + `Right Click` not work after install strokes plus

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, software-conflict

I'd like to use `Mouse Right Button` as `Stroke Button` in `strokes plus`(http://www.strokesplus.com).
But I also prefer `open cmd in current folder` by `Shift` + `Right Click` .

Now `Shift` + `Right Click` could not trigger the `Right Click Context Menu` after install strokes plus, how to work around?

Comment: That software overwrites the OS settings. If you don't know how to properly configure it, read its documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figure it out. Add ignore key in preferences would works.

[image]